# TypeError: this.add is not a function in node js application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have mongoose version 2.6 and mongodb version is 2.2 I am trying to make CRUD application in which I define schema. By adding Schema in my project. I am getting this error: 'TypeError: this.add is not a function'

Following is my code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    email: { type: String },
    password: { type: String },
    forgotToken: { type: String }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
```

I don't know what is wrong in my code. From code model should be created without any error. Please help me out.

Comment: please share code having `this.add`. Also add `new` keyword in `new mongoose.Schema({...})`

Comment: That is come from schema.js file from node modules

Comment: Did the adding of `new` keyword solved your problem?

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to create a new instance of schema object by not putting new keyword in front of it.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String },
    email: { type: String },
    password: { type: String },
    forgotToken: { type: String }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
```